# Premake5: GLFW project does not compile under project kind "ConsoleApp"

Tags: c++, c++17, glfw, mingw-w64, premake

I have this strange problem where my GLFW project does not compile (I am using Mingw64 as my compiler) when I set the project kind to "ConsoleApp" in my Premake file. It works perfectly when the project kind is set to "WindowedApp", but I want to have debugging capabilities. Here is my Premake file:

```lua
workspace "EatOrDie"
    architecture "x64"

    configurations {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }

output_dir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}-%{cfg.buildcfg}"

project "EatOrDie"
    location "projects"
    kind "WindowedApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("builds/bin/" .. output_dir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("builds/obj/" .. output_dir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files {
        "src/**.h",
        "src/**.c",
        "src/**.hpp",
        "src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs {
        "vendor/glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64/include",
        "${VULKAN_SDK}/include/"
    }

    links {
        "vendor/glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64/glfw3",
        "${VULKAN_SDK}/lib/vulkan-1"
    }
```

This project will compile. When I set the project kind to "ConsoleApp" though, it gives me undefined references.

Comment: I think difference between `WindowedApp` and `ConsoleApp` are entry point (`WinMain` vs `main` or similar). it seems unrelated to "debugging capabilities". You might use different flag (`DEBUG`, `NDEBUG`, optimization level) depending of the configuration.

Comment: What I meant was I want to be able to print out important things like the number of extensions that my GPU supported (for Vulkan related stuff) and so on. I have tried running the executable from the terminal to see whether there is any output, but to my dismay nothing shows up.

Comment: Whoops, I answered the question myself. I have to link ```gdi32``` to use it in a console. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial mistake. I have to link the project with `gdi32` to display the window.